# Glimpse Error in VS2012 and IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

I am getting this error after installing Glimpse into a new project in MVC4.

```
Unhandled exception at line 1, column 1 in 
Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_metadata&hash=7767f6ca&callback=glimpse.data.initMetada

0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'glimpse is undefined'
```

I am using VS2012 and IE8.
I started with a new default MVC4 solution and installed Glimpse using Nuget.
I then ran the solution and navigated to Glimpse.axd and got the above error.

Any solutions please

Thanks
Parameswaran

Comment: Addendum: After I get thru the above errors then I get JSON is undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues with IE8 ([see aggregated issue here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/399))

If you test with a newer version of IE or with Chrome, then you should be fine